Controlling 5 V / 2 A power with a photodiode (sensing red/green LED)
I am trying to design a circuit that will switch a 5 V / 2 A power on or off depending on voltage on a photodiode. If the voltage on the photodiode is below 40 mV, then it should be “ON”, otherwise “OFF”.
I am new to electronics and I have designed a circuit to show the idea, but I am sure it is not correct. Can anyone please help me improve it?

(Longer story:
I have a home device with a LED power-on indicator. I want another device (powered from USB) to be turned on when this device is turned on. The only way to know the device is turned on is from its LED indicator. It glows either green (on) or red (off). I have found out that I can use an IR photodiode that I put directly onto the LED indicator and sense its voltage. When the LED is green, the photodiode gives around 15 mV, when the LED is red, the photodiode gives around 40 mV. My idea is to use a comparator, reference voltage and MOSFET to enable or disable the 5 V output.)

Welcome! Have you considered a transimpedance opamp? The voltage doesn’t change much but the current does from photodiodes, so you don’t have much swing to work with. Just a bias and series resistor would probably do the job too. If not, there are good mV ground sensing opamps available.

I don't have any knowledge about transimpedance opamp, but I can research it, thank you for the idea! @winny

The circuit shown might work with some comparators, fail with others. Show a part #, and show how you intend to power it.

So the circuit is not totally wrong? I was not sure if I connected it all correctly... And I have no idea about part number of the comparator, I thought I could maybe use LM393, but don't have experience with it. And it will be powered from a good quality USB wall adapter, 5V/2A.

place a red filter over the photodiode ... a piece of red mylar from Christmas wrap might work

A TIA would make much more sense here than using the diode in photovoltaic mode (for which you've also drawn it upside down).

A photodiode isn't a good voltage signal source, unless you have a load resistor across it.   The photodiode is approximately a current source at low terminal voltages.

Using the Voltaic Mode with a PD or a Red LED for a light sensor.
I added a current limiter feedback.
Be aware that this is not power efficient using 5V and some parts need Pd rating.
Do you have any better specs?

